# AutoIt Send() whithout interrupting pressed keys

Tags: keyboard, autoit

Understanding the problem is quite easy - each time AutoIt is sending its stuff, a keyboard-user's stuff gets missed exactly the `Opt("SendKeyDownDelay",50)` time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the *Opt("SendKeyDownDelay",50)* statement is given and a keyboard-emulation is absolutely welcome.

AutoIt was very user-friendly there.
Finally,

```
Send("{X DOWN}")
Sleep(50)
Send("{X UP}")
```

And the *Opt("SendKeyDownDelay",0)* statement can do exactly what was excepted.
You'd need a function to send strings, but the key down time is easy to change with that method.

Maybe someone can use that, i can. *(Remember to replace X with a key of your choice)*
Thanks for your tips and greetings
Tim

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to send is
    ControlSend ( "", "", "", "e")

This will send an "e" to an active window without interrupting the input.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send data as quickly as possible in addition to not interrupting you can use the **clipboard**.

Here are three examples:

**Example one (listed above):**

```
$data = "I want to send this!"
ControlSend( "", "", "", $data )
```

**Example Two (fastest way):**

```
$data = "I want to send this!"
ClipPut($data) ;puts text in clipboard
ControlSend( "", "", "", "^v" ) ;pastes text instantly
```

**Example Three (clipboard without ControlSend):**

```
$data = "I want to send this!"
ClipPut($data)
Send("^v")
```

Additionally you can clear the clipboard with: `ClipPut('')`